# How to make other threads wait for a given task result

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have a heavy operation with a server, lets call it `String getData()`, I want always to get an updated version of this data, so I do not apply a cache to the call.

My goal now is to avoid more than one `getData` call running at the same time. Making all the calls done after the first call (but before the first request end) to wait for the first result.

Example:

```
Thread 1           Thread 2              Thread 3            
getData()
                   getData()[waiting]
                                         getData()[waiting]
result1 received   return result1        return result1
                   getData()
                   result2 received
                   return result2
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: So you only want one `Thread` ever running `getData`? Do that then - have a single `Thread` that when `getData` is called, blocks until it's complete - during that time return a `Future`. When that call is complete, `complete` the `Future` and wait for the next call.

Comment: there are 3 calls for the data from different points of the app.

Comment: And all three could wait for the same countdownlatch or something, then collect the result.

Comment: Your getData() what does it return? can you give an example of your code. If its only a string, you should look into StringBuffer (This is Thread-Safe) Or if you use a List, replace with CopyOnWriteArraySet<T>

Comment: This seems to be a great introduction to threading using an executor service and a `Future`: http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/

Comment: For clarity - if all reading threads call `getData` at near-enough the same time, would they all recieve the **same** data object or would each recieve a newly gathered one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution that does not involve any extra thread is to use [`ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> instance = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>(1);

private String getData() {
    final AtomicBoolean computed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    String data = instance.computeIfAbsent("KEY", () -> { 
        String data = internalGetData(); 
        computed.set(true);
        return data;
    });
    if(computed.get()) {
       instance.clear();
    }
    return data;
}

private String internalGetData() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My rather inelegant idea is to store a `Future` when the first call comes in, and return this same future to other calls received while the first call is still pending. Then, when the first call completes, discard this `Future`, and create a new one when the next request comes in:

```
class OneAtATime<T> {
  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  private final Supplier<T> supplier;

  private Future<T> future;

  OneAtATime(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  synchronized Future<T> submit() {
    if (future == null) {
      future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, executor);
      future.thenRunAsync(() -> {
        synchronized (JustOneExecutor.this) {
          future = null;
        }
      }, executor);
    }
    return future;
  }
}
```

Comment: With Java 8 this could be tidied somewhat.

Comment: @kstandell - your edit was correct. Community should not have rejected it - applied.

Comment: @BoristheSpider tidied somewhat with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the functionality of a `BlockingQueue`.

```
BlockingQueue<Data> dataQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
```

Now all you need to do is `dataQueue.take()` and only one thread will get it's own data.

Comment: I don't think it is what OP wanted. I understood he wants to consolidate requests. Meaning: First request starts datacollection from remote server. All subsequent requests shall queue up and receive the same result as soon as the data collection is done. All "requesters" have the same data now. Next request will start a new request to remote server.

Comment: @Fildor - I interpreted *I want always to get an updated version of this data, so I do not apply a cache to the call* as **never deliver potentially stale data**, i.e. ever call must return a new `datum`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I think the idea is that the method is called, then every next call blocks for the result. Once the method returns, all waiting threads are given the result. The system then resets.

Comment: I referred to the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @Fildor - It is confusing. I think changing it to your interpretation could be done using a `BlockingQueue<Future<Data>>`.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Or I don't get it. With a blocking queue, a take from different threads will block, ok. But as soon as an element arrives only one of those threads will "win", right? So even if you put a Future into the BlockingQueue, there is nothing won. Except you put as many times the same Future as there were Threads waiting ... But then I could as well return the same Future in the first place, without Queue. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @Fildor - I think you are right, but I would prefer to hear from OP before deriving an alternative version - especially as they say *so I do not apply a cache to the call* because that would be what this suggestion would be.

Comment: Not exactly. Introducing a cache would be serving the same data to any call until the cache is invalidated. So calls that come in after the remote request has finished would also receive that cached stuff. What I *think* the OP is trying to do is minimize remote calls because they are obviously very expensive and long-enduring. So he wants to feed any call the most recent result that has finished being retrieved from remote. See the difference? But I agree to wait for OP to comment.